# How to remove parts of a string that comes after a 'general pattern' using Python

Tags: python, string, split

Lets say I have a string like this:

```
str = 'Friends.S02E05.720p.BluRay.x264.MiniShare.x265'
```

I want to remove everything after 'S02E05'. This is probably easy. Maybe I can go with something like this:

```
splitter = 'S02E05'
s1 = str.split(splitter)[0] + splitter      # ==> Friends.S02E05
```

My problem is, how can I make this code work if the `splitter` part was 'S03E07'? Basically I'm looking for something to work after 'S*E*'. What can I do?

Comment: You can use [`^(.+?\.S.*?E.*?)\.`](https://regex101.com/r/ISV8rL/1) regular expression `re.search(r"^(.+?\.S.*?E.*?)\.", s).group(1)`. Docs: [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search)

Comment: @OlvinRoght Thank you very much. Will it work even if S and E are lower case?

Comment: It will work if you pass [`re.IGNORECASE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.IGNORECASE) flag.

Comment: @OlvinRoght could you please tell me, what if I want to remove everything except the pattern itself? I mean if the string is 'Friends.S02E05.720p.BluRay.x264.MiniShare.x265', how can I end up only with 'S02E05'?

Comment: Strings are immutable in python, so *"remove everything except"* anyway will end up with allocation of new string with desired content. You can just reassign variable though if it fits as a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Using a regular expression, you could capture the content that you're looking for:

```py
import re


INPUT_STRING = ...
PATTERN = "(.*S\d+E\d+)"

search_obj = re.search(PATTERN, INPUT_STRING)
print(search_obj.group(1))
```

**EDIT:** To support S and E upper or lowercase, you could use a flag or just include `s` and `e` in the regex:

```
PATTERN = "(.*[Ss]\d+[Ee]\d+)"
```

---

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/w4wGw9/1)